# How to reverse the order of list in Android?

Tags: android, list

I am developing in Android , I read the file from the folder and put into list.

The list has two value: **1.Name** **2.Time**

It can show the List like the following code:

```
 for(int i=0;i<fileList.size();i++){
        Log.i("DownloadFileListTask", "file mName("+i+") = " + fileList.get(i).mName);
        Log.i("DownloadFileListTask", "file mTime("+i+") = " + fileList.get(i).mTime);
 }
```

And the log is like the following:

```
file mName(0) = /DCIM/100__DSC/MOV_0093.LG1
file mTime(0) = 2015-04-15 14:47:46
file mName(1) = /DCIM/100__DSC/PICT0094.JPG
file mTime(1) = 2015-04-15 14:47:52
file mName(2) = /DCIM/100__DSC/MOV_0095.LG1
file mTime(2) = 2015-04-15 14:48:04
file mName(3) = /DCIM/100__DSC/MOV_0096.LG1
file mTime(3) = 2015-04-15 14:48:12
file mName(4) = /DCIM/100__DSC/MOV_0097.LG1
file mTime(4) = 2015-04-15 14:48:20
file mName(5) = /DCIM/100__DSC/MOV_0098.LG1
file mTime(5) = 2015-04-15 14:50:26
```

From the log , the early time is at the first object. But I want reverse its order.

How to reverse the order of list in Android?

Comment: do you want to sort it or just revert its order?

Comment: Sorry my bad , I just want to reverse its order.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use [Collections.reverse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)):

```
List myOrderedList = new List(); // any implementation
Collections.reverse(myOrderedList);
// now the list is in reverse order
```

Also, if you are the one adding the elements to the list, you can [add the new items at the top](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(int,%20E)) of the list, so later you don't have to reverse it:

```
List<Integer> myOrderedList = new List<>(); // any implementation
myOrderedList.add(1); // adds the element at the end of the list
myOrderedList.add(0, 2); // adds the element (2) at the index (0)
myOrderedList.add(0, 3); // adds the element (3) at the index (0)
// the list is: [3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Props for the Collections usage. I think the second suggestion would cause way too much unnecessary overhead if you are using an ArrayList, since it will copy all previous items into a new array with the new item prepended to it. If you're using LinkedList, you can use the add(0, x) approach without any worries, though.

Comment: yes, I agree. It depends on how the list is iterated later and its proper implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Create an ArrayList of Hashmap put both values inside it, by using for loop. After that use `Collections.reverse()` **to reverse you array value**.